# lightning-vertical-navigation item not showing as selected

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using the `lightning-vertical-navigation`. The navigation items are being rendered dynamically from a list of records, and the `selected-item` property can be set dynamically by code, rather than (or as well as) by user interaction.

In most circumstances everything is working well. However, on some changes an item is not selected even though the value of the `selected-item` property *does* exist as a name for one of the navigation items. I cannot understand why it does it in some circumstances and not others.

```
<lightning-vertical-navigation
    selected-item={selectedItem}
    onselect={handleSelectItem}>

    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section label="Items">

        <template for:each={items} for:item="item">
            <lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon
                key={item.Id}
                label={item.Name}
                name={item.Name}
                icon-name="utility:setup">
            </lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon>
        </template>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
</lightning-vertical-navigation>
```

Comment: What is in your `handleSelectItem`? Is the issue only happening with user-selected items?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves No, it is happening I think when the items are dynamically change, even though the `selectedItem` value *does* match the `item.Name` of one of the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my bug. I thought I'd post this here just in case it helps someone else.

When my `items` data changed dynamically, the `item.Name` property might change to something different for an `item` record. **But**, the `item.Id` *which I was using as the key in the `for:each` loop would remain the same*.

So, my issue was simply that the `for:each` loop wasn't re-rendering as expected because the `item.Id` that I was using as the key wasn't changing.

As soon as I changed the key to use `item.Name`, the `for:each` loop re-rendered when the name of an item changed.